# How to get branch specific SVN revision numbers in TeamCity

Tags: svn, teamcity

I have multiple svn roots configured in TeamCity.  They all point to the same *repository*, but different *paths* (branches).  All branches return the same value for revision.  I want the branch specific revision numbers.

Here is an excerpt from the build log after I've [dumped](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Predefined+Properties#PredefinedProperties-ServerBuildProperties) all the defined properties:

```
vcsroot.3_0_11__SP6_.url = https://svn.devlan.local/Enigma/branch/release/3.0.11/
vcsroot.trunk.url = https://svn.devlan.local/Enigma/trunk/
system.build.vcs.number.trunk = 9602
system.build.vcs.number.3_0_11__SP6_ = 9602
```

Clearly different locations in the svn tree, but same revision number.

How can I get branch specific revision numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to make multiple *VCS Roots* in your Administration settings and apply each one to the appropriate build.  For instance, if

- svn://196.168.0.1/software

is your SVN repository, then you might have VCS Roots for each of the following projects:

- svn://196.168.0.1/software/agent/trunk
- svn://196.168.0.1/software/server/trunk
- svn://196.168.0.1/software/database/trunk

"Branch-specific" revisions is sort of a misnomer, but each of those VCS Roots will use the branch's most recent repository revision number in its `build.vcs.number`.

Comment: I am set up as you describe.  Yet all roots return the same build.vcs.number.

Comment: I think I was dealing with a bug in TeamCity.  Since asking this question I've upgraded us to TC 5.1.1 and it works as you describe.

Comment: look like does not work in TeamCity 8.1.5. even when I use Checkout Rules the same. no luck. It keep showing the latest revision number no matter in what Branch (path) you are.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with TC 9.1.3 have you found a solution?

Comment: Using TC 9.1.7 - same problem - any news?